# Bash: grep selected text from a file

Tags: text, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, file1 :

```
abc/def/ghi/ss/sfrere/sfs
xyz/pqr/sef/ert/wwqwq/bh
```

file2:

```
ind abc def
bcf pqr sss
```

i wish to grep text file from file1, such that any words on any line of file2 match on one line of file1, so in this case answer would be first line, as abc and def are present in first line of file1. 2 or more words from lines of flie 1 should match in any line of file 2.

Comment: pqr appears in line 2, so why do you not want line 2 in your output?

Comment: sss and bcf both are not there in second line, two of three should be there

Comment: So, to match a line in file 1 there must exist at least 2 words from a line in file 2? Or is it exactly 2 words, or is 3 words OK too?? Please add these details to the question.

Comment: 3 are ok too, more then 2 should match.

Comment: What happens if a word from file2 appears twice in a line of file1? Should that line get printed?

Comment: Here's a crazy way to do it: `egrep --color=always -f <(tr ' ' '|' < file2) file1 | tr -cd '3\n'` - this will print `3` times the number of matches for each line, so `33` followed by `3` in your example.  Any line with two or more `3`s printed is therefore a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a){c=0;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){if(index(i,$j)>0)c++}if(c>=2)print i}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

**Explanation**

`FNR==NR{a[$1];next}` will iterate through first `File1.txt` and store lines in `a`.

`for(i in a)` will loop through the above stored lines,

`c=0` just to have a number check to keep track of number of columns matched.

`for(j=1;j<NF;j++)` loop through columns in lines of `File2.txt`

`if(index(i,$j)>0)c++` increment counter if one of the columns in `File2.txt` is in a line of `File1.txt`.

`if(c>=2)print i` Your given condition that it should match at least 2 columns, then we print line from `File1.txt`.

---

This is the most straight forward way that I could think of, I'm sure there are crazier ways to do this.

Comment: @NooB8374 Could you tell me what exactly it is printing?

Answer (score 0):

on huge file

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/(\1.*\2)|(\2.*\1)|(\1.*\3)|(\3.*\1)|(\2.*\3)|(\3.*\2)/' file2 >/tmp/file2.egrep
egrep -f /tmp/file2.egrep file1
rm >/tmp/file2.egrep
```

create a temporary pattern matching for egrep based on file2 content